# About a expression in solid state physics

Tags: solid-state-physics

When calculating electron density of metal with basic jellium model
$$\rho(\vec r)=2\sum_{|k|<k_F} \langle\vec k|\vec r\rangle \langle \vec r|\vec k\rangle $$

"as $V\rightarrow \infty $ , $\frac 1V \sum_{|k|<k_F} \rightarrow \int \frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^3}$ "

I'm not clear about the derivation of that. Is it a result of Block Theorem? or is it a general result?

With Block condition the result is clear because we can imagine each wave occupy $\frac {(2\pi)^3}{L_xL_yL_z}$ in reciprocal space, since k should be $\vec k=(2\pi n_x/L_x,2\pi n_y/L_y,2\pi n_z/L_z)$

Answer (score 0):

The result is the result of the definition of the $|\mathbf{k}\rangle$ states as the Fourier transform of the position basis
$$
|\mathbf{k}\rangle = \int_V\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}\; e^{-\imath \mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}}|\mathbf{r}\rangle
$$
This definition is enough to tell you that the separation of states in $k$ goes like $\frac{1}{L}$ in order to have a complete, and not an over- or under-complete basis.

This result does not depend on Bloch's Theorem, which tells you that this particular basis will be eigenstates of the Hamiltonian. You can, however, write down this basis without referring to any particular Hamiltonian. (It simply may not be very useful to do so if the Hamiltonian you are dealing with does not have transnational symmetry.)

Comment: where does the factor of  $(2\pi)^3$ come from?

Comment: The factors of $2\pi$ come from the fact that either the Fourier transform or the inverse Fourier transform must have a factor of $2\pi$ in it. I skimmed over it as it is just a constant factor and derivations of it can easily get bogged down in details.

Comment: your explanation is some kind of philosophy I think... I'm confusing about the serious derivation